# Is it possible to read raw voltage values from iPhone CMOS sensor?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am not an iOS developer, and I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this question, but wondered whether using the developer sdk (or other means) it is possible to read voltage from the CMOS sensor. I am curious because I thought it might be cool to turn my phone into a solar scintillation seeing monitor (see:[Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintillation), [practical example](https://www.ecu.edu/cs-cas/physics/upload/An-Inexpensive-Solar-Scintillation-Seeing-Monitor-Circuit-with-Arduino-Interface-final2.pdf)) for collecting data on "seeing" quality and quantifying low altitude particulate matter by observing light scatter.

From briefly skimming over the [iOS SDK reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation), I know you can read sensor data (but I think at a lower resolution than I want) and one can even probe the proximity sensor on the front of the phone (used for detecting ambient light and when your face is up against the device), but I think you can only call upon it's state (i.e yes it is on, no it is off).

Does anyone have any experience with working with image processing with iPhone images who might have insight? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting idea. Unfortunately, the wrong venue.

Comment: Thanks @Trenton_M I have posted in the signal processing channel. I hope that might be the correct place? I am not sure where to post!!!

Comment: My guess is, look at the [camera related sdk](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/) and post specifically to an apple developer site.  I doubt you will be able to access anything so direct as voltage levels without hardware hacking the phone.  Possibly reframe the question from a software development perspective, nevermind mentioning accessing CMOS voltage levels.